# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

Tags: java, android, character-encoding, android-4.2-jelly-bean

In simulator I can run my app, but on device with Jelly Bean OS I get a crash. Any idea why?

```
07-04 12:51:57.576 18243-18279/com.j4nos.moviebuffs6 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-7940
          java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
          at com.j4nos.moviebuffs6.Utility$1.run(Utility.java:52)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
```

This is the line I need character encoding:

`byte[] out = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html It was added in API Level 19 ( Android 4.4 )

Comment: What can I use insead of `StandardCharsets`?

Comment: Fidor ist right! StandardCharset doesn't exist in Jelly Bean.

Comment: I would always use UTF-8

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`StandardCharsets` [was added in API Level 19](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html). It is not available for any of the Jelly Bean versions of Android.

Comment: How would you downgrade my codeline? `byte[] out = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: @János: Use `getBytes()` instead of `getBytes(Charset)`.

Comment: @János You can also use `getBytes("UTF-8")` .

Comment: IDE suggested this, yet it didn't check for minSdk... Reported here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136845068

Answer (score 4):

There are various overloaded `.getBytes()` method is declared in `String` Class.

```
  public void getBytes(int, int, byte[], int);
  public byte[] getBytes(java.lang.String) throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
  public byte[] getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset);
  public byte[] getBytes();
```

You can use any of it. but you should try this..

```
 byte[] out = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

instead of

```
byte[] out = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is: Do you want to support Jelly Bean?

If yes: You can instead use the String-Parameterized version of the `getBytes` Method. You could even split codelines to use one version over the other depended on API Version running. (I do **not** recommend this!)

If no: Just restrict your app to a minimum API-Version equal to or higher than 19.

Answer (score 0):

As many mentioned, you can just use `"UTF-8"` in place of `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`

If you right click and 'go to source' on that variable you'll see this, where you see that the variable UTF_8 is tied to the string value "UTF_8"

You can see the other charsets string variables as well.

[image]